# How can I make a variable also fillable?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I assign the variable 't' to make my translations in my file shorter.

```
{% assign  t = site.data.translations %}
```

translation file: `_data/translations.yml`

```
hello:
  en: "hello"
  nl: "hallo"
```

What I now write is:

```
{{ t['hello'][page.lang] }}
```

Can I get rid of '[page.lang]' because it is repetitive code. Is there a possibility to do something like this to my variable 't' where {0} is fillable?

```
{% assign  t = site.data.translations{0}[page.lang] %}
{{ t['hello'] }}
```

Comment: It is not possible to do what you're looking for directly in Liquid. You'll have to write a plugin in Ruby to get the desired functionality.

Comment: @ashmaroli I Changed the order in my translation file so my variable 't' I assign: {% assign  t = site.data.translations[page.lang] %} Now I can use it as {{ t['hello'] }}

Answer (score 0):

In `_data/translations.yml` I changed the order by putting the page.lang before the keyword.

```
en:
  hello: "hello"
nl:
  hello: "Hallo"
```

Now I can use:

```
{% assign  t = site.data.translations[page.lang] %}
{{ t['hello'] }}
```